# can i mix syntax blade and javascript to get path img?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-10

I want get img path from my database in my script

```
const modalSelect = document.querySelector('#modal-select')
        const list = document.querySelectorAll('#modal-option')

        modalSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            const option = modalSelect.options[modalSelect.selectedIndex].text
            const imgOpt= '{{ $products->where('name', 'option')->get('image') }}'
            

            list.forEach((element, i) => {
                const valueList = element.value

                if (valueList == option) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: option[0].toUpperCase() + option.slice(1),
                        text: "Modal with a custom image.",
                        imageUrl: "imgOpt",
                        imageWidth: 400,
                        imageHeight: 200,
                        imageAlt: option + " image"
                    });
                }
            });
        })
```

I tried searching for data with `where` and mix with const `option` in my script, but it didn't work, I don't know how to combine it

Comment: The blade code runs on the server before you load the page, and before the JS runs in the browser. Therefore it cannot take input from JS, and it certainly knows nothing about JS variables

Answer (score 0):

You can not use client code into server. Why are you querying in js it is bad prectice. You need to add ajax call for getting image from server using on change. Below is sample code you need to change according to your need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#modalSelect').change(function() {
    const selectedOption = $('#modalSelect option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-image', 
        data: { option: selectedOption },
        success: function(response) {
            const imgOpt = response.image;
           // your logic here
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
        }
    });
});
```

});